# Google Game Services onPeersDisconnected/onP2PDisconnected not being called

Tags: android, google-play-games

As in the title I've been able to connect to **Google Game Services**, exchange data between two devices and everything is running fine, except one thing: **disconnection callbacks**.

I tried to intercept both onPeersDisconnected and onP2PDisconnected without any success. The onP2PDisconnected method is being called in the device that get disconnected from Internet but not into device that is still online (so there is no way to tell the player that the other one got disconnected).

After the match is started it seems that the second device is never notified of the accidental disconnection. If the user close the game properly the onPeersLeft method is being called thought.

Is a ping between the two devices really necessary to overcome this "bug"? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code I use:

```
void startQuickGame() {
    // quick-start a game with 1 randomly selected opponent
    final int MIN_OPPONENTS = 1, MAX_OPPONENTS = 1;
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(MIN_OPPONENTS,
            MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    mListener.switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();
    resetGameVars();
    getGamesClient().createRoom(rtmConfigBuilder.build());
}
```

And here the simple listeners:

```
@Override
public void onPeersDisconnected(Room room, List<String> peers) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPeersDisconnected");
    updateRoom(room);
}

void updateRoom(Room room) {
    Log.d(TAG, "UpdateRoom: "+room.getParticipants().size());
    mParticipants = room.getParticipants();
}

@Override
public void onP2PDisconnected(String participantId) {
    Log.d(TAG,  "onP2PDisconnected");

}

public int getPartecipantsInRooom(){
    if(mRoom != null)
        return mRoom.getParticipants().size();
    else
        return -123456;
}
```

Note that calling getPartecipantsInRooom() after one of the two devices disconnects always return 2, and updateRoom never get called.

Comment: Answering my own question I noticed that the method onP2PDisconnected is getting called, but after 60+ seconds!! So it's kind of useless... I'm going to use some timer that sends pings to the other devices every X seconds... This way the user doesn't have to wait for 60+ seconds to know that the match cannot continue.

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it, to help others who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure this might not work for you, for my applications I use this to let me know when another Participant has left the Room, and it is called immediately :

```
@Override
    public void onPeerLeft(Room room, final List<String> participantIds) {


        this.mRoomCurrent = room;
        this.mRoomId = this.mRoomCurrent.getRoomId();
        this.mParticipants = this.mRoomCurrent.getParticipants();

        int connected = 0;
        for (Participant p : room.getParticipants()) {
            if(p.getStatus() == Participant.STATUS_JOINED) {
                connected += 1;
            }
        }

        final int fconnected = connected;
        for (String s : listIgnoreTheseIDs) {
            //checkint to see if we care anymore about this ID.. if out of game already.. nope
            if(s.equals(participantIds.get(0))){
                return;
            }
        }
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mGHInterface.onPeerLeft(fconnected, participantIds.size()); 
                }
            });
        }
```

No idea why there are two items, but like you, I realized the onPeersDisconnected() isn't that reliable, but onPeerLeft() normally gets back to the other devices in under 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

onPeerDisconnected() handles disconnects. So if somebody is still in the application but the network connection is lost, this is called for him.

onPeerLeft() handles participants who leave a room. This is called when somebody explizit leaves the room in the application or the application is minimized, and the room is left on the androids onStop() or onDestroy() callback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making two player game. So I use this approach

```
@Override
public void onPeerLeft(Room room, List<String> peersWhoLeft) {
    updateRoom(room);
    Toast.makeText(MyLauncherActivity.this, "Other player left the game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    quitGame();
}
```